# How do I find out what other packages depend on a specific package?

Tags: package-management, manjaro, pacman

I am fairly new to linux. I use Manjaro.

I ran `pacman -Qe | less` and among the list of packages, I noticed:

```
jdk8-openjdk 8.u282-1
jfsutils 1.1.15-7
jre8-openjdk 8.u282-1
jre8-openjdk-headless 8.u282-1
```

Is there a way I can find out what packages depend on the packages listed above?

I am basically trying to find out why I have `jdk8-openjdk 8.u282-1` and `jre8-openjdk 8.u282-1` and if nothing uses them, I'd like to remove them.

But how can I find out if anything else is using them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```bsh
pacman -Qi jdk8-openjdk jfsutils jre8-openjdk jre8-openjdk-headless
```

will display information about the given packages, including the list of packages that depend on them ("Required By") and that optionally require them ("Optional For").

You may want to apply a filter to the output and only select the relevant information:

```bsh
pacman -Qi jdk8-openjdk jfsutils jre8-openjdk jre8-openjdk-headless |
  awk '/(^Name)|(^Required By)|(^Optional For)/'
```

A similar result (with one dependency per line) can be obtained using `pacinfo` from the `pacutils` package. In this case, add the `local` prefix to each package name to limit the results to your installed packages:

```
pacinfo local/jdk8-openjdk local/jfsutils ...
```

Arch Linux also has `pactree` from the `pacman-contrib` package, which is a dependency tree viewer. I can not check this because I am not a Manjaro user but, looking at the relevant [GitLab page](https://gitlab.manjaro.org/packages/core/pacman/-/blob/master/PKGBUILD), the `pacman` package on Manjaro seems to include the content of Arch's `pacman-contrib` too.
You may use it to list the packages that depend on `jdk8-openjdk` with:

```bsh
pactree -r jdk8-openjdk
```

and, to also include optional dependencies:

```bsh
pactree -ro jdk8-openjdk
```

Comment: thank you @fra-san, that worked beautifully. My apologies for not marking it as answer sooner.

Comment: @J86 No problem at all. Glad to see this worked for you.